# При сериализации объектов записывать фиксированное количество байт

Tags: c#, дерево, сериализация

Здравствуйте.

Существует такие классы: дерево `Btree<TKey, TValue>`, страница с узлами `Page<TKey>` (на корневую страницу в `Btree` есть указатель), в странице есть список узлов `SortedList<TKey, Node>`, (в Node, кроме полей `DataPosition` и `ChildPosition`, ничего не определяется), количество узлов, естественно, варьируется от порядка дерева. Сохранение страниц и данных в файле.

Теперь собственно вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы объект `TKey` сохранялся в файл и занимал там определенное фиксированное количество байт? Например, в самом простом случае, если TKey это string, а string бывает разной длины, то нужно где-то задавать длину максимальной строки (то бишь ключа).

Немного поразмыслив, ничего более умного чем интерфейс `ISizeFixed` не придумал. Однако хотелось бы, чтобы стандартные примитивные типы (int, char...) могли бы быть ключами без упаковки их в класс-оболочку, реализующий этот интерфейс.

Есть еще какие-нибудь варианты? Может я в принципе спроектировал систему неправильно?

---

upd0: необходимость фиксированного размера взялась из того, что количество узлов в странице может изменяться (но их там может быть не более 2t-1, где t - порядок дерева), а в файле этих страниц может быть много и расположены они плотно. Соответственно, при размещении страницы в файле, в нее сразу добавляется 2t-1 узлов-пустышек, а потом, при действительном добавлении элементов, узлы-пустышки заменяются на добавляемый элемент.

Возможно, это можно реализовать иным образом, если есть идеи, мне будет приятно их узнать.

---

<s>Еще немного подумав, решил сделать несколько перегрузок конструктора `Btree` для каждого из примитивных типов, и перегрузку для объектов реализующих `ISizeFixed`. Но все еще жду каких-нибудь иных идей.</s> Тоже не годится.

---

Вообще, очень бы хотелось какой-нибудь кастомный форматер, который при сериализации проверял длину записи и, если она меньше требуемой, дописывал недостающие байты (ну и кидал исключение, если ограничение превышено)

Comment: Непонятно, откуда вообще взялась необходимость фиксированного размера объекта.

Comment: > Возможно, это можно реализовать иным образом, если есть идеи, мне будет приятно их узнать.

Именно так. Почему бы не использовать какую-нибудь встраиваемую СУБД вроде SQLite?

Comment: А почему бы не реализовать интерфейс [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx)? Непонятно, однако, как вы сможете сериализовать объект (например, строку) размером в 100 байт при ограничении в 50 байт.

Comment: @VladD, Если ограничение в 50 байт, то при попытке записать объект в 51 байт и более будет ошибка. На то оно и ограничение.

Comment: @Flammable, это учебное задание. Прошу прощения, что не поставил метку

Comment: А размер файла в каких пределах?

Comment: @Flammable, в общем, без ограничения

Comment: Тогда у вас впереди куча развлечений. В начале файла резервируете кусок и храните в нем массив индексов (смещений от начала файла, по которым хранятся данные). Реализуете логику добавления/удаления данных с обновлением таблицы индексов, изменение размеров таблицы индексов и дефрагментацию всего файла.

Comment: С интерфейсов и пустышками всё-таки по проще будет :)